# Не отрабатывает autoprefixer в сборке vite для vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vite

Делал небольшой тестовый проект на Vue для наработки навыка и закрепления знаний. Сборка на vite. При build обнаружил, что в стилях нет префиксов в нужных css свойствах. Не могу понять в чем причина. Вроде в vite.congig все указано

```
    export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  css: {
    postcss: {
      plugins: [autoprefixer],
    },
  },
  test: {
    environment: "jsdom",
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@": fileURLToPath(new URL("./src", import.meta.url)),
    },
  },
  server: {
    host: true,
    port: 8080,
  },
});
```

в package.json нужные зависимости поставлены:

```
"browserslist": [
    "last 2 years",
    "> 1%",
    "not dead"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "@pinia/testing": "^0.1.3",
    "@rushstack/eslint-patch": "^1.5.1",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^4.4.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^8.0.0",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^2.4.1",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.17",
    "eslint": "^8.52.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.18.1",
    "jsdom": "^22.1.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.33",
    "prettier": "^3.0.3",
    "sass": "^1.69.5",
    "vite": "^4.5.0",
    "vitest": "^0.34.6"
  }
```

Но префиксы не появляются. Что необходимо сделать, чтоб исправить?
Полный код тут: https://github.com/MaksBmt/notepad-vue